# NLog UDP Multicast (or Broadcast)

Tags: nlog, .net-framework-version

Can I set NLog target as UDP Network with Multicast or Broadcast? How to?

I tried to find the way in NLog site, but I couldn't.
[NLog site](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Network-target)

I expected that it can be specific by target attribute like 'UDP-Type', but don't know how.

Comment: NLog NetworkTarget will enable UDP Broadcast when using IP-address `255.255.255.255`. See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ipaddress.broadcast